# Jenkins “Publish over FTP plugin” returning “534 Policy requires SSL” for file upload

Tags: ssl, jenkins, ftp, jenkins-plugins, ftp-client

I am trying to configure "**Publish over FTP plugin**" for uploading files to FTP site (SSL enabled) from Jenkins (v2.7.4).
The check box "*Use FTP over TLS*" is enabled in the FTP host configuration (under Manage Jenkins > Configure system) and "*Trusted Certificate*" added.

"Test Configuration" is Successful, however file upload is failing with error : "***534 Policy requires SSL***"

Find below the verbose output from console :

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/TEST_FTP
[TEST_FTP] $ /bin/sh -xe /opt/tomcat/temp/hudson6047550741121880978.sh
+ touch test.txt
FTP: Connecting from host [localhost]
FTP: Connecting with configuration [site1] ...
220 Welcome to XXXXXXXXXXXXXX FTP Services
AUTH TLS
234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
FTP: Logging in, command printing disabled
FTP: Logged in, command printing enabled
CWD /site1/upload
250 CWD command successful.
TYPE I
200 Type set to I.
CWD /site1/upload
250 CWD command successful.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (XX,XX,XX,XX,XX,XX).
STOR test.txt
534 Policy requires SSL.
FTP: Disconnecting configuration [site1] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Could not write file. Server message: [534 Policy requires SSL.
]]
Build step 'Send build artifacts over FTP' changed build result to UNSTABLE
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

Are there any additional configurations required for this plugin to work? Couldn't find any specific instruction in the wiki page : https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ftp

Answer (score 1):

From [RFC 2228](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2228.txt), it could be that the security level is insufficient. Negociating TLS on the command port is probably not enough for this server and if it's required to also encrypt the data with a PROT P command (following a PBSZ command) then you are blocked with your problem.

> The server will reply 534 to a STOR, STOU, RETR, LIST, NLST, or
>   APPE    command if the current protection level is not at the level
>   dictated    by the server's security requirements for the particular
>   file    transfer.

You can activate the debugging then we can confirm everything is ok with the handshake and that it's a problem of insufficient security, by adding  -Djavax.net.debug=all to your Jenkins startup.

It seems this Jenkins plugin doesn't support data channel encryption. Open a a feature request.

Comment: Thanks @Eugène Adell for taking the time to respond.
I have enabled javax.net debug logs and could see that the handshake is successful. There are no other 'SSL Exceptions' in the logs, except "534 Policy requires SSL".
Is there anything specific that I should be looking for in the logs?

Comment: No. Were you able to upload a file with FileZilla or with a curl command ? To make sure it's possible to upload anything.

Comment: Yes. Filezilla and even lftp works without any issues.

Comment: Yep, seems this Jenkins plugin doesn't support data channel encryption for me also, error "521 PROT P required".  I could remove/lower the requirement at the server end but why take the risk?  Going to script the FTP with something like WinSCP.  Shame really, cause the plugin almost worked for my need.